# Stratified Sampling in Python without scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector which contains 10 values of sample 1 and 25 values of sample 2.

```
Fact = np.array((2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2))
```

I want to create a stratified output vector where :

sample 1 is divided in 80% : 8 values of 1 and 20% : 2 values of 0.

sample 2 is divided in 80% : 20 values of 1 and 20% : 5 values of 0.

The expected output will be :

```
Output = np.array((0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

How can I automate this ? I can’t use the sampling function from scikit-learn because it is not for a machine learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get your desired result, with reproducibility of output added.  We draw random index values for each of the two groups from the input (`fact`) array, without replacement.  Then, we create a new output array where we assign `1`'s in locations corresponding to the drawn index values and assign `0`'s everywhere else.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import RandomState

rng = RandomState(123)

fact = np.array(
    (2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2),
    dtype='int8'
)

idx_arr = np.hstack(
    (
        rng.choice(np.argwhere(fact == 1).flatten(), 8, replace=False),
        rng.choice(np.argwhere(fact == 2).flatten(), 20, replace=False),
    )
)

out = np.zeros_like(fact, dtype='int8')
np.put(out, idx_arr, 1)

print(out)
# [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
```